# Converting HTML table data to CSV and XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, csv

I'm building a table script and one of the functionalities is to convert XML, CSV data to HTML and vice-versa.

I found some similar scripts on the web, that converts CSV to HTML and vice-versa but didn't find for XML.

I'm writing  the script from scratch, but I thought I'd better read few scripts before I write my own, to avoid mistakes and bugs. My question is, do you have/know a script that does this work?

Also any other advice, comment or idea is appreciable. Thanks!

(Note: I use jQuery as Framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV to html is easy assuming the columns are fixed, HTML to CSV is tricky if the earlier assumption fails. XML to HTML is not straight forward - reasons: 1. name spaces  2. multi-valued data ( forget absence of schema or DTD). Retaining commutative property is not easy without making trade-offs.